# Woocommerce Booking - Get a specific value from "Data" Cart item object

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have this array, that is dumped from WooCommerce using these lines:

```
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
    // some code here…
}
```

If I make a raw output of my cart ($items) and I get this:

```
["f584d8671586d336d84e8cf9ed43303c"]=> array(11) {
    ["booking"]=> array(15) {
        ["_year"]=> int(2016)
        ["_month"]=> int(8)
        ["_day"]=> int(28)
        ["_persons"]=> array(1) {
            [0]=>   int(1)
        }
        ["_date"]=> string(9) "2016-8-28"
        ["date"]=> string(13) "28 août 2016"
        ["_time"]=> string(5) "21:30"
        ["time"]=> string(11) "21 h 30 min"
        ["_qty"]=> int(1)
        ["Personnes"]=> int(1)
        ["_start_date"]=> int(1472419800)
        ["_end_date"]=> int(1472421600)
        ["_all_day"]=> int(0)
        ["_cost"]=> int(0)
        ["_booking_id"]=> int(13013)
    }



    ["product_id"]=> int(12856)
    ["variation_id"]=> int(0)
    ["variation"]=> array(0) { }
    ["quantity"]=> int(1)
    ["line_total"]=> float(0)
    ["line_tax"]=> int(0)
    ["line_subtotal"]=> int(0)
    ["line_subtotal_tax"]=> int(0)
    ["line_tax_data"]=> array(2) {
        ["total"]=> array(0) { }
        ["subtotal"]=> array(0) { }
    }
    ["data"]=> object(WC_Product_Booking)#11131 (20) {
        ["availability_rules":"WC_Product_Booking":private]=> array(0) { }
        ["id"]=> int(12856)
        ["post"]=> object(WP_Post)#11132 (24) {
            ["ID"]=> int(12856)
            ["post_author"]=> string(2) "14"
            ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2016-08-16 22:04:09"
            ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-08-16 20:04:09"
            ["post_content"]=> string(0) ""
            ["post_title"]=> string(10) "La Cuchara"
            ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) ""
            ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish"
            ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open"
            ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed"
            ["post_password"]=> string(0) ""
            ["post_name"]=> string(12) "la-cuchara-2"
            ["to_ping"]=> string(0) ""
            ["pinged"]=> string(0) ""
            ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2016-08-16 22:13:52"
            ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2016-08-16 20:13:52"
            ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) ""
            ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
            ["guid"]=> string(59) ""
            ["menu_order"]=> int(0)
            ["post_type"]=> string(7) "product"
            ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) ""
            ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0"
            ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw"
        }
        ["product_type"]=> string(7) "booking"
        ["shipping_class":protected]=> string(0) ""
        ["shipping_class_id":protected]=> int(0)
        ["total_stock"]=> NULL
        ["supports":protected]=> array(0) { }
        ["price"]=> string(1) "0"
        ["wc_display_cost"]=> string(0) ""
        ["wc_booking_base_cost"]=> string(0) ""
        ["wc_booking_min_duration"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["wc_booking_cost"]=> string(0) ""
        ["wc_booking_has_resources"]=> string(2) "no"
        ["wc_booking_has_persons"]=> string(3) "yes"
        ["wc_booking_has_person_types"]=> string(2) "no"
        ["wc_booking_min_persons_group"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["tax_status"]=> string(7) "taxable"
        ["stock_status"]=> string(7) "instock"
        ["manage_stock"]=> string(2) "no"
    }
}
```

I would like to use specific data values in some php variables, and I don't find the right way to achieve this…

How can I do to get the specific value from ["wc_booking_has_resources"]?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST** — Try first this (but I am unsure as I think it can be an object, so may be it will not work):

```
echo $items[0]['data']['wc_booking_has_resources'] . '<br>';
```

**SECOND** — With a foreach loop it will work certainly:

```
$items = WC()->cart->get_cart();

foreach($items as $item) { 
    $item_data = $item['data'];
}

// displaying the value for test
echo 'Booking has ressources: ' . $item_data['wc_booking_has_resources'];

// or may be this one (as $item['data'] is an object)
echo 'Booking has ressources: ' . $item_data->wc_booking_has_resources;
```

One of these will work, for sure…

---

**Update related to author comments**

How to get The booking try one of these:

```
// first (very unsure of this one)
$item_data =  $items[0]['data']['id'];

echo $item_data['id'] . '<br>'; // not sure this one work
```

Using a for each loop it will be much better:

```
$items = WC()->cart->get_cart();

foreach($items as $item) { 
    $item_data = $item['data'];
}

// As $item['data'] is an object
$booking_has_resources = $item_data->booking_has_resources;

// displaying
echo 'Booking has ressources: ' . $booking_has_resources;
```

**This should work**

Comment: Thank you and what about the booking id please

Comment: Hi what about the booking id please ?!!